# Oracle - hierarchical bottom up query with time constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that stores the relationships between organizational units.
These relations can change in the time, so it's perfectly normal to have an object thet refers to a parent yesterday, and to another parent today.
A constraint in DB ensures that an object can refers only to a parent in a given time (1:1 relation)

Now I want a query that returns the path from the leaf to the root, the only valid path in the desired period.

I am able to make the query run if I have only one relation, but if I insert two consecutive relation my query fails, returning not only my path, but also the other organization objects not belonging to my path

These are the relations

```
-- old situation graph
--           1
--       /   |  \
--      11   12  13
--      |    |
--     111  121
--           |
--         1111
--
-- current situation graph
--           1
--       /   |  \
--      11   12  13
--      |    |
--     111  121
--      |
--    1111
```

With only one relation I get this result for today and yesterday (OK)

```
'CURRENTSITUATION'  KY_UNI_ORG_INF  KY_UNI_ORG_SUP
Current situation   1111            111
Current situation   111              11
Current situation   11                1
Current situation   1                 0

'OLDSITUATION'  KY_UNI_ORG_INF  KY_UNI_ORG_SUP
old situation   111             11
old situation   11               1
old situation   1                0
```

but with two relations (uncommenting the DML sentence) I got the WRONG situation

```
'CURRENTSITUATION'  KY_UNI_ORG_INF  KY_UNI_ORG_SUP
Current situation   1111            111
Current situation   111              11
Current situation   121              12  -- Not in my path
Current situation   12                1  -- Not in my path
Current situation   11                1
Current situation   1                 0
Current situation   1                 0

'OLDSITUATION'  KY_UNI_ORG_INF  KY_UNI_ORG_SUP
old situation   1111            121
old situation   121             12
old situation   111             11  -- Not in my path
old situation   11               1  -- Not in my path
old situation   12               1
old situation   1                0
old situation   1                0
```

Following some DDL

```
CREATE TABLE BORG_APP_UNI_ORG 
(
  KEY_TAB NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, KY_UNI_ORG_SUP NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, KY_UNI_ORG_INF NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, DATA_INIZIO DATE NOT NULL 
, DATA_FINE DATE NOT NULL
)
```

DML

```
INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES (    1,  0,    1, trunc(sysdate-30), trunc(sysdate+30) );
INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES (   11,  1,   11, trunc(sysdate-30), trunc(sysdate+30) );
INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES (   12,  1,   12, trunc(sysdate-30), trunc(sysdate+30) );
INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES (   13,  1,   13, trunc(sysdate-30), trunc(sysdate+30) );
INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES (  111, 11,  111, trunc(sysdate-30), trunc(sysdate+30) );
INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES (  121, 12,  121, trunc(sysdate-30), trunc(sysdate+30) );
-- old relat                                                
-- INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES ( 1111,121, 1111, trunc(sysdate-30), trunc(sysdate-1) );
-- new relat                                                
INSERT INTO BORG_APP_UNI_ORG VALUES ( 1111, 111, 1111, trunc(sysdate),    trunc(sysdate+30) );
```

and the query

```
-- Current
select 'Current situation', r.ky_UNI_ORG_INF, r.ky_UNI_ORG_SUP
from 
    BORG_APP_UNI_ORG r
WHERE 
    trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN r.data_inizio and r.data_fine
CONNECT BY ky_uni_org_inf  = PRIOR ky_uni_org_sup
START WITH ky_uni_org_inf = 1111
order by level
    ;

-- Old
select 'old situation',r.ky_UNI_ORG_INF, r.ky_UNI_ORG_SUP
from 
    BORG_APP_UNI_ORG r
WHERE 
    trunc(sysdate-1) BETWEEN r.data_inizio and r.data_fine
CONNECT BY ky_uni_org_inf  = PRIOR ky_uni_org_sup
START WITH ky_uni_org_inf = 1111
order by level
;
```

Comment: If you filter data at first you get [correct result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da4d0/1).

Comment: @PonderStibbons Your link is very useful... many thanks. Paolo